# XSL changing text based on proximity to elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a number of 'corrections' to various text in a large corpus in XML,  identifiable based on proximity to elements (while copying a document using XSL 3.0).

For example, I need to move all '.' from outside to inside an element `<date>` like this:

```
  <seg><date>foodate</date>. Some variable text here.</seg>
```

to:

```
  <seg><date>foodate.</date> Some variable text here.</seg>
```

Or change the text based on the proximity of 'foo' to `<date>` in:

```
  <seg><date>foodate</date> foo some variable text here</seg>
```

to:

```
  <seg><date>foodate</date> foo2 some variable text here</seg>
```

I'm having trouble isolating the strings and performing functions on them based solely on proximity to other elements (not a general change of all text containing the string in question).

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: For the second problem with the `foo` proximity I think you need to be more precise as to what you want to check there, what is supposed to happen with `<seg><date>foodate</date> foobar some text</seg>`, do you want that to become `<seg><date>foodate</date> foo2bar some text</seg>`? So it is not clear whether a simple `matches(., '^\s*foo')` suffices to identify the text or whether you want to match on words or other tokens.

Comment: To clarify, the second item: change the string 'foo' to 'foo2' only when 'foo' is found as the first word immediately after `<seg><date>foodate</date>...`

Comment: I have added a second example to try to implement that requirement although the concept of a "word" is difficult to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write match patterns like `seg/date[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[starts-with(., '.')]]]` which matches `date` children of `seg` elements where the next sibling of the `date` element is a text node starting with a dot `.`, and then you only need to transform the contents to add the dot and need a template for the text node to remove the dot respectively the first character:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="seg/date[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[starts-with(., '.')]]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select=". || '.'"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="seg/text()[ starts-with(., '.') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::date]]">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMee

The second condition can use a similar approach to match on the text node and manipulate it although in general the concept of a "word" is more difficult to match on with the regular expression language supported by XSLT/XPath 2 or 3 as I don't think it has a way to match on word boundaries. Here is some attempt to match on the start of a text node with optional white space followed by some term like `foo` followed by non-word characters or the end of the string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="search-term2" as="xs:string">foo</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="replacement-term2" as="xs:string">foo2</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="seg/date[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[starts-with(., '.')]]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select=". || '.'"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="seg/text()[starts-with(., '.') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::date]]">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="seg/text()[matches(., '^\s*' || $search-term2 || '(\W|$)') and preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::date]]">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^(\s*)(' || $search-term2 || ')', '$1' || $replacement-term2)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMee/1

Comment: This will take some experimenting tomorrow. Is string matching in XSL case-sensitive? For example if I want to replace 'Foo' with 'foo2' but not 'foo'?

Comment: The regular expressions are by default case-sensitive, but you can add a flag `i` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags as an optional argument e.g. `matches(exp1, exp2, 'i')`

Comment: In the first example, I'm unsure what is happening with the XPATH in   `'<xsl:value-of select=". || '.'"/>' ? Is the double-pipe a concatenation operator in place of the XPATH concat function?

Comment: Returning to the first example, if '<date>' has an attribute, it doesn't get copied over. Tested in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWcDMee/1

Comment: If you expect the elements you transform to have attributes to be copied as well then obviously any `<xsl:template match="foo"><xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy></xsl:template>` needs to changed to handle the attributes as well with either `<xsl:template match="foo"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>...</xsl:copy></xsl:template>` (as long as the identity transformation template respectively `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"` is in place) or alternatively instead of the `apply-templates` use `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>`.

Comment: Thanks. In the first example, I'm unsure what is happening with the XPATH in `'<xsl:value-of select=". || '.'"/>' ? Is the double-pipe a concatenation operator in place of the XPATH concat function?